# Error while returning the number of count of collections in firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm developing an admin app in that i'm tired to return the number of users from firebase, i got few help from stackoverflow and was able to print in the terminal but its returning null on the app can someone please help me.this my code

```
    class _AdminState extends State<Admin> {



  Future<String> getUsersCount() async{
    var length = -1;
    await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments().then((myDocuments){
      print("${myDocuments.documents.length}");
      length = myDocuments.documents.length;
    });
    return Future.value(length.toString());
  }




  Page _selectedPage = Page.dashboard;
  MaterialColor active = Colors.indigo;
  MaterialColor notActive = Colors.grey;
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;



  bool isDelete= true;
  var values;

  TextEditingController categoryController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController brandController = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _categoryFormKey = GlobalKey();
//GlobalKey<FormState> _brandFormKey = GlobalKey();
// BrandService _brandService = BrandService();
  CategoryService _categoryService = CategoryService();





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() => _selectedPage = Page.dashboard);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.dashboard,
                        color: _selectedPage == Page.dashboard
                            ? active
                            : notActive,
                      ),
                      label: Text('Dashboard'))),
              Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() => _selectedPage = Page.manage);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.sort,
                        color:
                        _selectedPage == Page.manage ? active : notActive,
                      ),
                      label: Text('Manage'))),
            ],
          ),
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: _loadScreen());
  }



  Widget _loadScreen() {
    switch (_selectedPage) {
      case Page.dashboard:

        return FutureBuilder(
            future: getUsersCount(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> text) {
              print(text);
              if(text== "-1"){
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      subtitle: Text('Admin View', textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 29.0,
                            color: Colors.indigo,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                    Expanded(child: GridView(
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0), child: Card(
                          child: ListTile(title: FlatButton.icon(
                              onPressed: null,
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.directions_boat, color: Colors.black,),
                              label: Text("Boats", style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 9, color: Colors.indigo),)),
                              subtitle: Text('3', textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: active, fontSize: 50.0),)),
                        ),
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                          child: Card(child: ListTile(
                              title: FlatButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.people, color: Colors.black,),
                                  label: Text("Users", style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 9, color: Colors.indigo),)),
                              subtitle: Text(text.data != null ? text.data : '',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(color: active, fontSize: 50.0),
                              )),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
                          child: Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                                title: FlatButton.icon(
                                    onPressed: null,
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.bookmark, color: Colors.black,),
                                    label: Text("Bookings", style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 8, color: Colors.indigo),)),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  '120',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: active, fontSize: 50.0),
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],

                    ),

                    ),
                  ],
                );
              } })
```

i was returning a null string value but when include this set of lines Text(text.data??'default value') i was able to clear that error but still not able to clear my issue someone please help me
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add **await** before getting data from Firestore, since it is and async and you are not waiting for the result and returning the value which is initialized to 0

```
    Future<String> getUsersCount() async {
        var length = 0;
        await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments().then((myDocuments){
          print("${myDocuments.documents.length}");
          length = myDocuments.documents.length;
        });
        return Future.value(length.toString());
    }
```

As you can see the value of users count(36) is getting printed but it is not return because the return gets called before the async execution is getting finish..

Comment: but when run the app its taking some time to display the user value means its displaying empty and then loading the value can't i do anything for that?

Comment: Text(text.data!=null?text.data:'') can i change this and do something else?

Comment: thats an async method, what u can do this by the time your data gets loaded you can show CircularProgressIndicator() and when the data gets loaded you can show the widget you want

Comment: @Rohit posted a new answer for this.. check it once

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `length to -1` in getUsersCount method and then in `build method` before returning the `cloumn widget` check the text (snapshot value) :

```
if (text == "-1"){
  return Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.red,)
  );
} else{
  return Column(....)
}
```

Comment: i have implemented the above lines in mycode but's still displaying the empty screen in the beginning

Comment: i have updated the latest code in my post please do check

Comment: @Rohit if condition is not getting called, so what you can do is refer this and give a try https://medium.com/@jimmyhott/using-futurebuilder-to-create-a-better-widget-4c7d4f52a329